# Dynamically accessing object property in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

I am making a game in TypeScript. The game has an inventory system with several values like this:

```
export const Inventory = {
    food: 0,
    medicine: 0,
    rifleAmmo: 0,
    pistolAmmo: 0
}
```

Currently I am managing adding and subtracting from the Inventory with the following function

```
export const removeFromInventory = ({amount}: itemInterface) => {
    return Inventory.rifleAmmo  = Inventory.rifleAmmo - amount 
}
```

I want to make this function accept a dynamic value for the name and the amount, currently I have this from other answers here on Stack Overflow:

```
enum itemType {
    'rifle-ammo'
}
interface itemInterface {
    amount: number,
    item: itemType
}
export const AddToInventory = ({amount, item}: itemInterface) => {
    return  Inventory[item]  = Inventory.item + amount 
}
```

However I am getting the error that either a string cannot be used as an index type, having the type be "any" doesn't help either. I know this is possible but my TypeScript skills are lacking.  How can I dynamically access an object's property in TypeScript?

Comment: If you really want to do this, you can cast it as `any` as `const t = Iventory as any`, then `t[item]` should be fine.

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.` do you suggest another way of doing this? I am very open to your expertise

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting in the question above? Inventory.item doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wez6YN) meet your needs? (note that your names seem to be using almost exactly the opposite of the standard `lowerCamelCase` for values and `UpperCamelCase` for types, so I fixed that) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Jcalz's solution is working for me. Thank you for also fixing my casing. 
It seems the answer was using the `keyof` operator.

Comment: The answer added by @dave is essentially the same so I'm not going to bother writing my version up

Comment: Just like this: 
`export const AddToInventory = ({ amount, item }: itemInterface) => {
    const t = Inventory as any;
    return t[item] = t.item + amount;
};`

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp: in case you are not aware, Stack Overflow permits all contributors to change their username if they wish. Your username is rather needy, and appears to be self-labelling as incompetent. Might you change it to something more neutral, so that you don't feel that you are unable to do your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgdgNwnYB7ATiKBeKpKoBmUAkosmpgNwBQEAHmBsFAMapwDOLZSKGWXAG8aUMVEKpUAEwBcUAAwAaUeIC2EaTFbwI85arHoYhADYQAgmrWp9K8VDAxuqU1Zv6aAXxp04AVzVYYAg1ABVwaBEHAHJjMwgAWgBDa1QY7xp4EPRCZNZoGBC1Mhy8gqho8VTUfxR5ALUAIwh0e3Ei0PkAawgQIlhyfkxMhiZ0FnYuFgtpaTDUXgoBHCgACiEauuAlYNCveU6SlFbyiABKHAA+SsModAhgf3Q4MSXhkABtI4BdMVx3pQvr8oABqKBbFBQTJAA)

```
type inventory = typeof Inventory;
export const Inventory = {
    food: 0,
    medicine: 0,
    rifleAmmo: 0,
    pistolAmmo: 0
}

enum itemType {
    'rifle-ammo'
}
interface itemInterface {
    amount: number,
    item: keyof inventory
}
export const AddToInventory = ({amount, item}: itemInterface) => {
    return  Inventory[item]  = Inventory[item] + amount 
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should probably remove `itemType` from here

Comment: instead of using the enum the solution was to use typeof and keyof `type Inventory = typeof inventory;
interface ItemInterface {
    amount: number,
    item: keyof Inventory
}`
Thank you for the help!